# Drawing the E-R Diagram - TikZ - Diagram Overflowing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following E-R diagram:

[image]

I am using the TikZ-er2 package. The package is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/pavel_calado/tikz-er2/wiki/Home). Now, I have completed almost 50% of the drawing. But, my TikZ picture appears in page 2 (article class and I have put landscape mode) and when the diagram is extended, it cuts off. How do I proceed? And I want to label my drawing as well. I can have a separate node for that, but are there any other ways.

Here is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every entity} = [top color=white,bottom color=blue!30,draw=blue!50!black!100,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{every attribute} = [top color=white, bottom color=yellow!20,
draw=yellow, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{every relationship} = [top color=white, bottom color=red!20,
draw=red!50!black!100, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{every edge} = [link]
\tikzstyle{every isa} = [top color=white, bottom color=green!20,
draw=green!50!black!100, drop shadow]
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10em]
    \node[entity] (student) {Student};
    \node[isa] (isa1) [below of=student, node distance=5em] {ISA} edge node [auto,swap] {disjoint} (student);
    \node[entity] (mtech-stud) [below left of=isa1] {MTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (btechproj) [below left of=mtech-stud] {No.-of-BTech-Projects} edge (mtech-stud);  
    \node[entity] (btech-stud) [below of=isa1] {BTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[entity] (phd-stud) [below right of=isa1] {Ph.D.$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (stud-id) [left of=student] {\key{student-id}} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (name) [above left of=student] {Name} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (fname) [above left of=name] {First-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (lname) [above right of=name] {Last-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (cgpa)  [above right of=student] {CGPA} edge (student);
    \node[relationship] (joins) [right of=student] {joins} edge [total] (student);
    \node[entity] (pgroup) [right of=joins] {Project-Group} edge [<-] (joins);
    \node[attribute] (group-id) [above left of=pgroup] {\key{group-id}} edge (pgroup);
    \node[derived attribute] (group-cgpa) [above right of=group-id] {group-CGPA} edge (pgroup);
    \node[multi attribute] (areas) [above right of=group-cgpa] {areas-of-interest} edge (pgroup);
    \node[relationship] (pgroup-guide) [right of=pgroup] {Project-Group-Guide} edge (pgroup);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First: don't use `tikzstyle`, but `tikzset` for your styles. Second: have a look to [How to scale a tikzpicture including texts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26846/13304), [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6388/13304) and [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36297/13304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few options:

First use `\resizebox`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    %% helps to see in upright direction in pdf
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every entity/.style={top color=white,bottom color=blue!30,draw=blue!50!black!100,drop shadow},
        every attribute/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=yellow!20,
                                  draw=yellow, drop shadow},
        every relationship/.style ={top color=white, bottom color=red!20,
                                  draw=red!50!black!100, drop shadow},
        every edge/.style = {link},
        every isa/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=green!20,
                                  draw=green!50!black!100, drop shadow},
        }
\begin{landscape}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight}{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10em]
    \node[entity] (student) {Student};
    \node[isa] (isa1) [below = of student, node distance=5em] {ISA} edge node [auto,swap] {disjoint} (student);
    \node[entity] (mtech-stud) [below left = of isa1] {MTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (btechproj) [below left = of mtech-stud] {No.-of-BTech-Projects} edge (mtech-stud);
    \node[entity] (btech-stud) [below = of isa1] {BTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[entity] (phd-stud) [below right = of isa1] {Ph.D.$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (stud-id) [left = of student] {\key{student-id}} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (name) [above left = of student] {Name} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (fname) [above left = of name] {First-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (lname) [above right = of name] {Last-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (cgpa)  [above right = of student] {CGPA} edge (student);
    \node[relationship] (joins) [right = of student] {joins} edge [total] (student);
    \node[entity] (pgroup) [right = of joins] {Project-Group} edge [<-] (joins);
    \node[attribute] (group-id) [above left = of pgroup] {\key{group-id}} edge (pgroup);
    \node[derived attribute] (group-cgpa) [above right = of group-id] {group-CGPA} edge (pgroup);
    \node[multi attribute] (areas) [above right = of group-cgpa] {areas-of-interest} edge (pgroup);
    \node[relationship] (pgroup-guide) [right = of pgroup] {Project-Group-Guide} edge (pgroup);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Second put your `tikzpicture` inside `adjustbox` environment from `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    %% helps to see in upright direction in pdf
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every entity/.style={top color=white,bottom color=blue!30,draw=blue!50!black!100,drop shadow},
        every attribute/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=yellow!20,
                                  draw=yellow, drop shadow},
        every relationship/.style ={top color=white, bottom color=red!20,
                                  draw=red!50!black!100, drop shadow},
        every edge/.style = {link},
        every isa/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=green!20,
                                  draw=green!50!black!100, drop shadow},
        }
\begin{landscape}
\begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10em]
    \node[entity] (student) {Student};
    \node[isa] (isa1) [below = of student, node distance=5em] {ISA} edge node [auto,swap] {disjoint} (student);
    \node[entity] (mtech-stud) [below left = of isa1] {MTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (btechproj) [below left = of mtech-stud] {No.-of-BTech-Projects} edge (mtech-stud);
    \node[entity] (btech-stud) [below = of isa1] {BTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[entity] (phd-stud) [below right = of isa1] {Ph.D.$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (stud-id) [left = of student] {\key{student-id}} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (name) [above left = of student] {Name} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (fname) [above left = of name] {First-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (lname) [above right = of name] {Last-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (cgpa)  [above right = of student] {CGPA} edge (student);
    \node[relationship] (joins) [right = of student] {joins} edge [total] (student);
    \node[entity] (pgroup) [right = of joins] {Project-Group} edge [<-] (joins);
    \node[attribute] (group-id) [above left = of pgroup] {\key{group-id}} edge (pgroup);
    \node[derived attribute] (group-cgpa) [above right = of group-id] {group-CGPA} edge (pgroup);
    \node[multi attribute] (areas) [above right = of group-cgpa] {areas-of-interest} edge (pgroup);
    \node[relationship] (pgroup-guide) [right = of pgroup] {Project-Group-Guide} edge (pgroup);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here the advantage is the picture is resized only if it exceeds a max height of `0.9\textheight`

Third, is to adjust each node distance instead of globally giving a value as you did. This is left to yourself.

Note that I have changed `tikzstyle`s (which are deprecated) to `tikzset` and added `positioning` library and changed all instances of `of =` to `= of`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution where `landscape` feature from `geometry` is used and `\resizebox`is used to 0.8`\textwidth` to prevent cutoff.  style format are defined in `tikzset`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every entity/.style = {top color=white,bottom color=blue!30,draw=blue!50!black!100,drop shadow},
every attribute/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=yellow!20,draw=yellow, drop shadow},
every relationship/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=red!20,draw=red!50!black!100, drop shadow},
every edg/.style={link},
every isa/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=green!20,draw=green!50!black!100, drop shadow}
}
%\begin{landscape}


\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \node[entity] (student) {Student};
    \node[isa] (isa1) [below = 1cm of student] {ISA} edge node [auto,swap] {disjoint} (student);
    \node[entity] (mtech-stud) [below left = 2em and 3em of isa1] {MTech$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (btechproj) [below left= 2em and -5em of mtech-stud] {No-BTech-Projs} edge (mtech-stud);  
    \node[entity] (btech-stud) [below = 0.2 em of isa1] {BTech$-$student} edge (isa1);

    \node[entity] (phd-stud) [below right = 2em and 3em of isa1] {Ph.D.$-$student} edge (isa1);
    \node[attribute] (btechproj1) [below left = 2em and -2em of phd-stud] {No-BTech-Projs} edge (phd-stud);  
   \node[attribute] (btechproj2) [below right = 2em and -2em  of phd-stud] {No-BTech-Projs} edge (phd-stud);

    \node[attribute] (stud-id) [above left = 2em of student] {\key{student-id}} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (name) [above = 2em of student] {Name} edge (student);
    \node[attribute] (fname) [above left = 2em of name] {First-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (lname) [above right =2em of name] {Last-Name} edge (name);
    \node[attribute] (cgpa)  [above right = 2em of student] {CGPA} edge (student);

    \node[relationship] (joins) [right = 2cm of student] {joins} edge [total] node[above ]{1...1} (student) ;
    \node[entity] (pgroup) [right = 2cm of joins] {Project-Group} edge [] node[above ]{1...1} (joins);
    \node[relationship] (pgroup-guide) [right = 3cm of pgroup] {Project-Group-Guide} edge node[above ]{1...1} (pgroup);

    \node[attribute] (group-id) [above left =1em  and 1em of pgroup-guide] {\key{Porject-Domain}} edge (pgroup-guide);
    \node[attribute] (group-cgpa) [above right = 1em  and 1em of pgroup-guide] {\key{Porject-title}} edge (pgroup-guide);


    \node[attribute] (group-id) [below left =1em  and 1em of pgroup] {\key{group-id}} edge (pgroup);
    \node[derived attribute] (group-cgpa) [below = 4em of pgroup] {group-CGPA} edge (pgroup);
    \node[multi attribute] (areas) [below right= 1em  and 1em of pgroup] {areas-of-interest} edge (pgroup);

 \node[entity] (faculty) [right = 1cm of pgroup-guide] {Faculty} edge node[above ]{1...1} (pgroup-guide);

 \node[attribute] (name1) [right = 2em of faculty] {Name} edge (faculty);
 \node[attribute] (fsc-id) [above = 2em of name1] {\key{Fsc-ID}} edge (faculty);
 \node[multi attribute] (special) [below = 2em of name1] {Specialization} edge (faculty);
 \node[attribute] (email) [below = 5em of special] {E-mail} edge (faculty);
 \node[multi attribute] (phones) [below = 4em of email] {Phones} edge (faculty);

 \node[attribute] (fname) [above right= 0.1em and 1em of name1] {First-Name} edge (name1);
 \node[attribute] (lname) [below right= 0.1em and 1em of name1] {Last-Name} edge (name1);


\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```