# grid and draw use different coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

The question is easy to explain with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm]
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: result of the mwe before]

In the output, `graph2` did quite surprise me --- it seems that the `grid` and the `--` to draw lines are using different coordinates. I was expecting that the grid would scale down as the line do... what am I missing?

(BTW --- also the fact that in neither graph the text is scaling down is quite surprising).

Comment: The default value for `grid`'s option `step` is `1cm`, not the `x` or `y` unit, whose default is also `1cm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

every thing is good the point A is (3,3) since (1,1) is in (0.5cm,0.5cm) you can set the step=1
like this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm]
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed, step=1] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);  % ---> step=1
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** for text scaleing you can see [How to scale a tikzpicture including texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts)

[image]

**Edit** about grid (this is only 1st tikzpicture)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed,step=0.5] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [very thin, color=gray, dashed,step=0.2] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
 \draw [color=green!50!black, ->] (0, 0) -- (3,3)  node[above right]{$\vec{A}$};
 \draw (0,5) node[below right]{graph 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks --- but I really still do not understand --- so the coordinates for grid and `--` are different by default? And why your example has text scaled --- I can't spot the  difference from my mwe in that sense...

Comment: @Rmano in my code i use [x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm,every node/.style={scale=0.5}] and [scale=0.5,every node/.style={scale=0.5}]

Comment: @Rmano i edit my answer traying to more explain about grid you shoud know that the step of grid is different from the unit of coordinates.

Comment: I still do not see the `every node` key in the code you posted in any of your answer --- a copy and paste problem?

Comment: i don't use it in the code posted but in the code used at home