# Scale parts of a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that there are several options to scale a whole tikz picture (e.g., `\resizebox`). However, I want to scale only some parts within a single tikz picture.

In my case I want to create some slides for a conference where one slide should be composed of different single (complex) tikz pictures that already exist. Furthermore, I want to have them partly overlapped. I already found `\begin{scope}[scale=.2] ... \end{scope}`. However, that does not work.

Here is MWE that should visualise what I mean:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
              node distance=.5cm,
              rect/.style={rectangle, draw, thick, inner sep=5pt, minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center, fill=white},
              ellips/.style={circle, draw, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=22mm, align=center, fill=white}]

    \node[rect] (A) at (-1, 0) {Stuff A};
    \node[rect] (B) [right= of A] {Stuff B};
    \node[rect] (C) [right= of B] {Stuff C};

    \node[ellips] (D) at (0,0) {As a whole};
    \node[ellips] (E) [below= of D] {we should \\ be scalable};
    \draw [draw, thick] (D.270) [] to node {} (E.90);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my real case the combination of `D` and `E`  is a rather complex tikz picture that I'd like to make smaller and to print 'above'/'between' `A`and `B`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure this will fit your needs, but you can try nesting with scaling both on the `tikzpicture` as a whole and on the nodes within (cf. [How to scale a tikzpicture including texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts)):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
        node distance=.5cm,
        rect/.style={rectangle, draw, thick, inner sep=5pt, minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center, fill=white},
        ellips/.style={circle, draw, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=22mm, align=center, fill=white}]

        \node[rect] (A) at (-1, 0) {Stuff A};
        \node[rect] (B) [right= of A] {Stuff B};
        \node[rect] (C) [right= of B] {Stuff C};

        \node (DE) [right= -5mm of A]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
                \node[ellips] (D) at (0,0) {As a whole};
                \node[ellips] (E) [below= 2cm of D] {we should \\ be scalable};
                \draw [draw, thick] (D.270) [] to node {} (E.90);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Producing (after fiddling with positioning):

[image]

Comment: I tried using scope, but [scale=0.5] did nothing.  [every node/.style={scale=0.5}] worked.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. However, it is not suited to scale a complex figure with an arrangement of several nodes and edges. However, I used and adapted your solution with the `\node (DE)`. Instead of the tikz code is just include the tikz picture as a pdf by using `\includegraphics[scale=0.7, keepaspectratio=true]{picture.pdf}`. That works splendid.