# I am creating a flow chart and the flowchart goes out of the page border. Could someone help me?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am creating a flow chart and the flowchart goes out of the page border. Could someone help me?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black,text width=3cm, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (dec1) [decision] {dec1};
    \node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1 , right of=dec1, yshift=-1.5cm, xshift=2cm] {dec2};
    \node (dec3) [decision, below of=dec1 , left of=dec1,yshift=-1.5cm , xshift=-2cm] {dec3};
    \node (dec4) [decision, below of= dec3 , right of=dec3,yshift=-1.5cm , xshift=1cm] {dec4};
    \node (dec5) [decision, below of= dec2 , left of=dec2,yshift=-1.5cm , xshift=0.3cm] {dec5};
    \node (dec6) [decision, below of= dec4 , left of=dec4,yshift=-1cm , xshift=-2.5cm] {dec6};
    \node (dec7) [decision, below of= dec5 , right of=dec4,yshift=-1cm , xshift=5.5cm] {dec7};

    \node (box1) [startstop,  below of=dec4, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.5cm ] {box1};
    \node (box2) [startstop,  below of=dec5, yshift=-1cm,xshift=0.5cm ] {box2};
    \node (box3) [startstop,  below of=dec6, left of=dec6 ,yshift=-1cm] {box3};
    \node (box4) [startstop,  below of=dec6, right of=dec6 ,yshift=-1cm] {box4};
    \node (box5) [startstop,  below of=dec7, left of=dec7 ,yshift=-1cm] {box5};
    \node (box6) [startstop,  below of=dec7, right of=dec7 ,yshift=-1cm] {box6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Maybe `scale` is an option:[How to scale a tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26846/124842)

Answer (score 5):

My modifications:

- Define tikzstyles `minsize` and `textwidth` to modify the minimum width etc. for all other tikzstyles (if you just scale to `0.5` the text will get very small).
- Use `below=of dec1` using the tikzlibrary `positioning` instead of `below of=dec1` (see [Difference between “right of=” and “right=of” in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz))
- If you use `below=of dec1, right=of dec1` as option, the first has no effect. Therefore use `below right=of dec1`. In this way, many manual adjustments (with `xshift` and `yshift`) can be saved. (A [solution without `xshift` and `yshift`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385709/123129) is given by Zarko)
- I use `\usepackage{showframe}` just to show the margin.
- Then you can use `scale=xx` and `every node/.style={scale=xx}` as Bobyandbob suggested in the comment.
- As Zarko and Torbjørn T. mentioned: `tikzstyle` is  deprecated. Instead `tikzset` should be used (see: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)).

Note: For the treelike structure you could also have a look at the [`forest`-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\usepackage{showframe}

\tikzset{
    minsize/.style={minimum width=15mm, minimum height=10mm},
    textwidth/.style={text width=15mm},
    startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minsize, text centered, draw=black,textwidth, fill=red!30},
    io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minsize, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    process/.style={rectangle, minsize, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    decision/.style={diamond, minsize, text centered, textwidth, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\title{test}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10mm, scale=0.65, every node/.style={scale=0.78}]
    \node (dec1) [decision] {dec1};
    \node (dec2) [decision, below right=of dec1, xshift=15mm] {dec2};
    \node (dec3) [decision, below left=of dec1, xshift=-15mm] {dec3};
    \node (dec4) [decision, below right=of dec3] {dec4};
    \node (dec5) [decision, below left=of dec2] {dec5};
    \node (dec6) [decision, below left=of dec4, xshift=-15mm] {dec6};
    \node (dec7) [decision, below right=of dec5, xshift=15mm] {dec7};

    \node (box1) [startstop, below=of dec4] {box1};
    \node (box2) [startstop, below=of dec5] {box2};
    \node (box3) [startstop, below left=of dec6, xshift=10mm] {box3};
    \node (box4) [startstop, below right=of dec6, xshift=-10mm] {box4};
    \node (box5) [startstop, below left=of dec7, xshift=10mm] {box5};
    \node (box6) [startstop, below right=of dec7, xshift=-10mm] {box6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use of `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. use `\tikzset` instead :)

Comment: @Zarko I modified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously need to move things closer together, the code below is one suggestion for doing that. I've changed a few things from your original code, but I'm not entirely sure if the output is correct. But to summarize the changes:

- `tikz` loads `xcolor`, so the `\usepackage{color}` is strictly speaking not necessary.
- The `showframe` package I added is *only* for the example, what it does is put a box around the text area. You want to remove it for your document.
- It may be better to load the `positioning` library and use `right=of` instead of `right of=`, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)
- You can't use both `below=of`/`below of=` and `right=of`/`right of=` for the same node. Whichever of those is used last will only take precedence over the other. This is why you needed all those extra shifts. But you do have `below right=of` which can be used instead.
- `\tikzstyle` is usually considered deprecated, and `\tikzset{style1/.style={...}, style2/.style={...}}` should be used instead, see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles) for some discussion around this.
- I've changed the `node distance` to `node distance=1cm and 2cm`. The first value is the vertical distance, the second is the horizontal. See section 17.5.3 *Advanced placement options* in the TikZ manual (for version 3.0.1a) for more details. That section describes the `positioning` library.
- There are still some manual `shift`s here and there, but less than it was.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the text boundaries
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.geometric,
  arrows,
  positioning % added
}

\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm,
    text centered,
    draw=black,
    text width=2cm, % modified
    fill=red!30,
    font=\small, % added
    inner sep=1pt % added
  },
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
  decision/.style={
    diamond,
    text centered,
    text width=2cm,
    draw=black,
    fill=green!30,
    inner sep=0pt % added
  },
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm]
\node (dec1) [decision] {dec1};
\node (dec2) [decision, below right=of dec1] {dec2};
\node (dec3) [decision, below left=of dec1] {dec3};
\node (dec4) [decision, below right=of dec3,xshift=-1.5cm] {dec4};
\node (dec5) [decision, below left=of dec2,xshift=1.5cm] {dec5};
\node (dec6) [decision, below=0mm of dec4,xshift=-20mm] {dec6};
\node (dec7) [decision, below=0mm of dec5,xshift=20mm] {dec7};

\node (box1) [startstop, right=2mm of dec6] {box1};
\node (box2) [startstop, left=2mm of dec7] {box2};
\node (box3) [startstop, below=of dec6,anchor=east,xshift=-3mm] {box3};
\node (box4) [startstop, below=of dec6,anchor=west,xshift=3mm] {box4};
\node (box5) [startstop, below=of dec7,anchor=east,xshift=-3mm] {box5};
\node (box6) [startstop, below=of dec7,anchor=west,xshift=3mm] {box6};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Many same adjustments but a few additional.

Answer (score 0):

one more variation (with smaller nodes' shapes and fonts, using only library `positioning` for node placement, nodes' styles, slightly modified are defined as `tikzpicture` options):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 14mm and 7mm,
     base/.style = {draw, text width=15mm, minimum height=9mm,
                    font=\small, align=center},
%
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
       io/.style = {base,
                    trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    trapezium stretches, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.2, fill=green!30},
                    ]
\node (dec1) [decision] {dec1};
\node (dec2) [decision, below right=14mm and 22mm of dec1] {dec2};
\node (dec3) [decision, below left =14mm and 22mm of dec1] {dec3};
\node (dec4) [decision, below right=of dec3] {dec4};
\node (dec5) [decision, below left =of dec2] {dec5};
\node (dec6) [decision, below left =of dec4 -| dec3.south] {dec6};
\node (dec7) [decision, below right=of dec5 -| dec2.south] {dec7};
%
\node (box1) [startstop, right=of dec6] {box1};
\node (box2) [startstop, left =of dec7] {box2};
\node (box3) [startstop, below left =of dec6.center] {box3};
\node (box4) [startstop, below right=of dec6.center] {box4};
\node (box4) [startstop, below left =of dec7.center] {box5};
\node (box6) [startstop, below right=of dec7.center] {box6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```