# Scaling TikZ matrix of nodes having shadowed nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to use TikZ' `matrix of nodes` for rebuilding a previously created image. The goal is the following:

[image: Target image]

There are two general questions I got for this:
1) Is there a more 'TikZy' way to create the rectangled shapes in the illustration with the respective sizes, spanning over multiple rows?
2) How can I scale the whole image, such that it will fit on a portrait a4paper (image below is created on landscape a3paper)?

What I did until now (code and current resulting image are attached below):

In order to create the shapes 'Job Builder', 'GNU Parallel', and 'Computing Cluster', I created nodes and fitted the respective rectangles to it.
If I now use the scaling as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts) (adding `[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]` to tikzpicture), the shadowed nodes acting as fitting points become visible (last image).
Also, the relation between nodes becomes weird. Is there any way to scale the whole illustration, as one can do that using the `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}` statement?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,matrix,fit}
\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    every path/.style={thick},
    grey_vertex/.style={rectangle, draw, thick, top color=white, bottom color=black!20, draw=black!50, align=center, minimum size = 10pt},
    edge_label/.style={auto, font={\tiny\itshape}},
    vertex_bg_good/.style={rectangle,thick,bottom color=green!20,top color=green!10}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix(m)[row sep=5mm, column sep=15mm, matrix of nodes, nodes={grey_vertex, circle, text width=4.7em}, font=\footnotesize]
            {
                {Parameters\\EA 1}  &                 & {Config\\EA 1}  &            & {EA\\Template}    & {Input\\Files}    & \node(mRes1){Results\\EA 1}; & \node(mSta1){Statistics\\EA 1};   \\
                {Parameters\\EA 2}  & \node(m22){};   & {Config\\EA 2}  &            &                   &                   & \node(mRes2){Results\\EA 2}; & \node(mSta2){Statistics\\EA 2};   \\
                                    &                 &                 & {jobs.sh}  & \node(mPar1){};   & \node(mPar2){};   &                              &                                   \\
                {...}               & \node(m42){};   & {...}           &            &                   &                   & \node(mResx){...};           & \node(mStax){...};                \\
                {Parameters\\EA n}  &                 & {Config\\EA n}  &            & \node(mclu1){};   & \node(mclu2){};   & \node(mResn){Results\\EA n}; & \node(mStan){Statistics\\EA n};   \\
            };
            \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(m22)(m42)]       (BG1)   {Job\\Builder};
            \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(mPar1)(mPar2)]   (BG2)   {GNU\\Parallel};
            \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(mclu1)(mclu2)]   (BG3)   {Computing\\Cluster};
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mRes1)(mSta1)] (mFRes1) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mRes2)(mSta2)] (mFRes2) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mResx)(mStax)] (mFResx) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mResn)(mStan)] (mFResn) {};
            \end{scope}
            \draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-2-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-4-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-5-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-1-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-2-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-4-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-5-3);
            \draw[->] (m-1-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-2-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-4-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-5-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-3-4) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (m-1-5) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (m-1-6) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (BG2) edge[bend left=30] (BG3);
            \draw[->] (BG3) edge[bend left=30] (BG2);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFRes1.south west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFRes2.south west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFResx.north west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFResn.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current result without scaling]
Current result without scaling on a3paper and landscape.

[image: Current result with scaling]
Current result with scaling on a4paper and portrait.

Comment: Scaling can be done by `\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=.1}]`

Comment: This works fine for all foreground items, can this also be applied to the background layer?

Comment: Sry, not seen the background items. I am at work now, will have a look when I am at home if nobody has answered until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid complication of layers (and others) rescaling, you can use `\resizebox`, except if the `tikzpicture` contens `&` due to matrix material. In this case, one has to change the `&` in to something else : for example `\&` as suggested by the manual and add the option : `ampersand replacement=\&`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lscape,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,matrix,fit}
\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    every path/.style={thick},
    grey_vertex/.style={rectangle, draw, thick, top color=white, bottom color=black!20, draw=black!50, align=center, minimum size = 10pt},
    edge_label/.style={auto, font={\tiny\itshape}},
    vertex_bg_good/.style={rectangle,thick,bottom color=green!20,top color=green!10}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
   \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            \matrix(m)[row sep=5mm, column sep=15mm, matrix of nodes, nodes={grey_vertex, circle, text width=4.7em}, font=\footnotesize]
            {
                {Parameters\\EA 1}   \&                  \& {Config\\EA 1}   \&             \& {EA\\Template}     \& {Input\\Files}     \& \node(mRes1){Results\\EA 1};  \& \node(mSta1){Statistics\\EA 1};   \\
                {Parameters\\EA 2}   \& \node(m22){};    \& {Config\\EA 2}   \&             \&                    \&                    \& \node(mRes2){Results\\EA 2};  \& \node(mSta2){Statistics\\EA 2};   \\
                                     \&                  \&                  \& {jobs.sh}   \& \node(mPar1){};    \& \node(mPar2){};    \&                               \&                                   \\
                {...}                \& \node(m42){};    \& {...}            \&             \&                    \&                    \& \node(mResx){...};            \& \node(mStax){...};                \\
                {Parameters\\EA n}   \&                  \& {Config\\EA n}   \&             \& \node(mclu1){};    \& \node(mclu2){};    \& \node(mResn){Results\\EA n};  \& \node(mStan){Statistics\\EA n};   \\
            };
           \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(m22)(m42)]       (BG1)   {Job\\Builder};
            \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(mPar1)(mPar2)]   (BG2)   {GNU\\Parallel};
            \node[grey_vertex, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=(mclu1)(mclu2)]   (BG3)   {Computing\\Cluster};
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mRes1)(mSta1)] (mFRes1) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mRes2)(mSta2)] (mFRes2) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mResx)(mStax)] (mFResx) {};
                \node[vertex_bg_good,draw,fit=(mResn)(mStan)] (mFResn) {};
            \end{scope}
            \draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-2-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-4-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (m-5-1) -- (BG1);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-1-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-2-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-4-3);
            \draw[->] (BG1) -- (m-5-3);
            \draw[->] (m-1-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-2-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-4-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-5-3) -- (m-3-4);
            \draw[->] (m-3-4) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (m-1-5) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (m-1-6) -- (BG2);
            \draw[->] (BG2) edge[bend left=30] (BG3);
            \draw[->] (BG3) edge[bend left=30] (BG2);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFRes1.south west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFRes2.south west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFResx.north west);
            \draw[->] (BG2.east) -- (mFResn.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Would this also be the recommended TikZ way?

Comment: It is a safe way to do it because it treats the the picture as an image dispite it components. In a tikzpicture there is several class of elements that don't scale together, ex: distance/coordinate (affected by scale option) on one side and text size in nodes and linewidth don't affected by scale option but by canvas tranformation. Apparently there is other complication with layers or fit stuff. One has to deal with each one with its way: resize box is a simpliest way.

Comment: Important , the manual says :`Just as important, when you use canvas transformations pgf loses track of positions of nodes and of
picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas transformations into account when it computes
coordinates of nodes (do not, however, rely on this; it may change in the future).` Probabely the fit library that works on nodes will loose the north.