# Add details to TikZ, woodworking diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, paper-size, technical-drawing

I am trying to recreate this hand drawn diagram of a wooden stand: [image]
Here is the .tex: (it is a bit longer than a MWE).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a2paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[minimum width=30cm, minimum height=30cm,draw,thick,rectangle](TopSquare){};
\node [below=10mm of TopSquare] {Top View}; 
\node [below=0mm of TopSquare] {30cm};
\node [rotate=90, left=5mm of TopSquare] {30cm};

\node[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=30cm,draw,thick,rectangle, right=25mm of TopSquare](SideView){};
\node[minimum width=14cm, minimum height=30cm,draw=none, right=25mm of TopSquare](Side){};
\node[below=10mm of Side]{Side View};
%\node [below=10mm of SideView] {Side View}; 
\node [below=0mm of SideView] {2cm};
%\node [rotate=90, left=5mm of SideView] {30cm};

\node[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle,below right=-20mm and 0mm of SideView](Sup1){};
\node[below=0mm of Sup1] {12cm};


\node[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle, right= 0mm of SideView](Sup2){};
%\node[below=0mm of Sup2] {12cm};

\node[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle,above right=-20mm and 0mm of SideView](Sup3){};
%\node[below=0mm of Sup3] {12cm};

\end{tikzpicture}
\section*{Instructions}
\begin{itemize}
\item\blindtext
\item\blindtext
\item\blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which leads to this pdf: (Screenshot, I added the red elements to show the issues.)[image]

- I want to scale the picture to an A3, but keep the font size. (Printing a scaled A2 on an A4 leads to difficult-to-read text. I am using `[a2paper]{geometry}` so that I can see the whole `tikzpicture`.
- I could make the figure smaller, i.e. `\node[minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm,draw,thick,rectangle](TopSquare){};`. But then I'd have to readjust all rectangles, etc.
- I'd like to add the red elements. The box in the long, vertical box of the side view is at the same height as the red circles in the smaller squares.
- Where the 12cm box meets the 2cm x 30 cm bar, there isn't a nice overlap.
- I'd like to add the dashed lines to show the smaller squares in the 30x30.
- The `\section*{Instructions}` will be filled with bullet items for my woodworker friend who will make this stand.

Comment: I'll look into the  `dimline` package to add lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the some answers to your some questions.

> I could make the figure smaller, i.e. \nodeminimum width=5cm, minimum
>   height=5cm,draw,thick,rectangle{};. But then I'd have to
>   readjust all rectangles, etc.

You can use some scaling options given in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26852/31034).

> I'd like to add the red elements. The box in the long, vertical box of
>   the side view is at the same height as the red circles in the smaller
>   squares.

The height and width of desired box was given by hand according to the circle and other dimensions.

> Where the 12cm box meets the 2cm x 30 cm bar, there isn't a nice
>   overlap.

To obtain a nice overlap, I have used the `xshift` and `yshift` options in draw
 command. (Adjusted by hand to best result).

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a3paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry} %<---- A3 landscape.
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}]% Scaling

\node[minimum width=30cm, minimum height=30cm,draw,thick,rectangle](TopSquare){};
\node [below=10mm of TopSquare] {Top View}; 
\node [below=0mm of TopSquare] {30cm};
\node [rotate=90, left=5mm of TopSquare] {30cm};

\draw[dotted] (TopSquare.north)--(TopSquare.south);
\draw[dotted] (TopSquare.west)--(TopSquare.east);
\path (TopSquare.center)coordinate(O)--(TopSquare.north east)coordinate(C);
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=4cm] at  ($(O)!0.5!(C)$)(D3) {} ;
\path (TopSquare.center)coordinate(O)--(TopSquare.north west)coordinate(D);
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=4cm] at  ($(O)!0.5!(D)$)(D4) {} ;
\path (TopSquare.center)coordinate(O)--(TopSquare.south west)coordinate(A);
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=4cm] at  ($(O)!0.5!(A)$)(D1) {} ;
\path (TopSquare.center)coordinate(O)--(TopSquare.south east)coordinate(B);
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=4cm] at  ($(O)!0.5!(B)$)(D2) {} ;

\node[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=30cm,draw,thick,rectangle, right=25mm of TopSquare](SideView){};
\node[minimum width=14cm, minimum height=30cm,draw=none, right=25mm of TopSquare](Side){};
\node[below=10mm of Side]{Side View};
%\node [below=10mm of SideView] {Side View}; 
\node [below=0mm of SideView] {2cm};
%\node [rotate=90, left=5mm of SideView] {30cm};

\path[dotted,draw] (SideView.east)coordinate(SL)--(SideView.west);
\path (SL)--(SideView.north west)coordinate(SVR);
\node [draw,rectangle,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=1cm] at ($(SL)!0.5!(SVR)$){};
\path (SL)--(SideView.south west)coordinate(SVRR);
\node [draw,rectangle,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=1cm] at ($(SL)!0.5!(SVRR)$){};

\node (Sup1) at (SideView.south east)[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle,xshift=5.99cm,yshift=1.01cm]{};
\node (Sup2) at (SideView.east)[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle,xshift=5.99cm,yshift=0cm]{};
\node (Sup3) at (SideView.north east)[minimum width=12cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick,rectangle,xshift=5.99cm,yshift=-1.015cm]{};

\draw[dashed](D3.90)--++(0:11cm);
\draw[dashed](D3.-90)--++(0:11cm);
\draw[dashed](D2.90)--++(0:11cm);
\draw[dashed](D2.-90)--++(0:11cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\section*{Instructions}
\begin{itemize}
\item\blindtext
\item\blindtext
\item\blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: @MaxR, Your welcome. Sorry for last claim that related to the `\section*{Instructions}`. I did not understand it.

Comment: Is there a way to only scale the image, not the text?

Comment: I think `\resizebox{<horizontal size>}{<vertical size>}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}` is works.