# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}: tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors

I have following tikzpicture in my presentation:

```
\begin{frame}{Unitary bounds}
\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{.7}{
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,opacity=.2] (-.5,-1) rectangle (4,3);
\fill[green!80!black,opacity=.2] (-.5,3) rectangle (4,5);
\draw[very thick,green!80!black] (-1,3) -- (5,3) node[right, black] {$\Delta=\Delta_A$};
\draw[very thick, green!80!black] (-1,1) -- (5,1) node[right,black] {$\Delta=\Delta_B$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$\Delta$};
\node at (2,2) {non-unitary};
\node at (2,0) {non-unitary};
\node at (2,4) {unitary};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}
\caption{Unitarity structure of superconformal multiplets.}\label{fig:unitarity}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

But unfortunately this lead to

`Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}`

Comment: don't put a center environment inside a scalebox. That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- After commenting out `center` environment and loading `tikz` package, your problem disappears.
- Also, you can void `\scalebox` by using `tikz` option `scale=0.7` instead. If you do want to scale the node text as well, use `every node/.append style={scale=0.7}` as suggested in [How to scale a tikzpicture including texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26852/79060).
- <strike>In the following example, `center` environment is replaced with `\centering`.</strike> Using `\centering` is not necessary, since `figure` environment centers its contents by default.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Unitary bounds}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, every node/.append style={scale=0.7}]
      \fill[red,opacity=.2] (-.5,-1) rectangle (4,3);
      \fill[green!80!black,opacity=.2] (-.5,3) rectangle (4,5);
      \draw[very thick,green!80!black] (-1,3) -- (5,3) node[right, black] {$\Delta=\Delta_A$};
      \draw[very thick, green!80!black] (-1,1) -- (5,1) node[right,black] {$\Delta=\Delta_B$};
      \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$\Delta$};
      \node at (2,2) {non-unitary};
      \node at (2,0) {non-unitary};
      \node at (2,4) {unitary};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Unitarity structure of superconformal multiplets.}\label{fig:unitarity}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]