# Why are minumum width and minimum height options not affected by scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have noticed that when I use the `scale` option in a TikZ picture, the values of `minimum width` and `minimum height` are not scaled. A MWE (both pictures are exactly the same, only the `scale` parameter changes):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 0) -- (4, 0);
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 2) -- (4, 2);
    \draw[dotted] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);
    \draw[dotted] (3, -1) -- (3, 3);
    \node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] at (1.5, 1) {A box};
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 0) -- (4, 0);
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 2) -- (4, 2);
    \draw[dotted] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);
    \draw[dotted] (3, -1) -- (3, 3);
    \node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] at (1.5, 1) {A box};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Bad scaling]

The problem would be fixed use `transform shape` on the picture; however, that would change the size of the text, too. Is not there any way to have coordinate-scalable boxes?

Comment: There are two types of scaling: coordinate and canvas. Add `transform shape` to the scaled tikzpicture. See [Correctly scaling a tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4338/4778)

Comment: Also, you should replace the `minimal` class with the `standalone` class.

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks, that works for the box - but it also affects text. I have reformulated the question; is it not possible to have scalable boxes without affecting the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scaling options applies to the whole node. This means that even the text is scaled and I don't think there is an option to avoid it.

However scaling does not apply to `\draw`. Attaching a node to a draw command will render the text immune to the scale command.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 0) -- (4, 0);
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 2) -- (4, 2);
    \draw[dotted] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);
    \draw[dotted] (3, -1) -- (3, 3);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[midway] {a box};
    %\node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] at (1.5, 1) {A box};
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 0) -- (4, 0);
    \draw[dotted] (-1, 2) -- (4, 2);
    \draw[dotted] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);
    \draw[dotted] (3, -1) -- (3, 3);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[midway] {a box};
    %\node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] at (1.5, 1) {A box};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```