# How to scale data text with diagram in tikz-timing?

Tags: fonts, size, tikz-timing, scale

I'm trying to generate timing diagrams of different sizes in a document with tikz-timing.

I have managed to scale the whole diagram using options like timing/unit or timing/wscale. I can also change the font size of the row names using timing/font=\large.

However, no matter what I do, the data text is always the same size and does not scale with the diagram.

Edit: I tried to use the resizebox command that was brought up in the comments, but now the signal names are huge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikztimingtable}[]
        Clock & 10{c} \\
        Signal &  z4D{Text}z \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
\\
\\

    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikztimingtable}[]
            Clock & 10{c} \\
            Signal &  z4D{Text}z \\
        \end{tikztimingtable}
    }
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

What I would like it to look like is this (MS Paint):

[image]

Any help is appreciated,

Felix

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557), including the `\documentclass` , `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: See this post also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4338/28557

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I added an MWE and rephrased my question. The resizebox unfortunately does not do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use the `scale` option along with the data text to scale it.
2. `xunit` and `yunit` can be used to scale the graph also.

These two settings combined can give you the desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/xunit=30,timing/yunit=30]
        Clock & 10{c} \\
        Signal &  z4D{[scale=1]Text}z \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}

    \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/xunit=30,timing/yunit=30]
         Clock & 10{c} \\
         Signal &  z4D{[scale=2] Text}z \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]