# Matrix using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations, matrices

I am working on my dissertation and I have no idea how I should do this in LaTeX.

And the shading definitely is challenging.

[image]

I have only been able to do this so far, I am still an amateur at it.

```
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   \left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
\y & \y    & \y   \\
   & \y   & \y R  \\
   &       & \y   \\
\end{array}
 \right]\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
        \\
       a_j \\
        \\
     \end{array}
   \right]=
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With TikZ `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,  positioning, patterns, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    every matrix/.append style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        },
    mylargenode/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=30pt,
        text height=20pt,
        text depth=10pt,
    },
    mylongnode/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=20pt,
        text height=40pt,
        text depth=30pt,
    },
    mysmallnode/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=20pt,
        text height=20pt,
        text depth=10pt,
    },
    mylonglargenode/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=30pt,
        text height=40pt,
        text depth=30pt,
    },
}

\begin{document}
With delimiters like in your image:
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    nodes={mylargenode},
    column 6/.style={nodes={mysmallnode}},
    row 6/.style={nodes={mylonglargenode}}
    ] (A) {%
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!10!white]| \\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!30!white]|\\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!50!white]|\\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue,dotted]| \\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!70!white]|\\
    &&&&& |[mylongnode,pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=blue!40!white, draw=blue]|\Dot{F}\\
    };
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \ind in {1,2,3,5}
    {
    \draw[green!70!black,fill=green!40!lightgray] (A-\ind-\ind.north west) -- (A-\ind-\ind.north east) -- (A-\ind-\ind.south east) -- cycle;
    \node[anchor=north east] at (A-\ind-\ind.north east) {R};
    }
\end{scope}
\draw[dotted, green!70!black] (A-4-4.north west) -- (A-4-4.north east) -- (A-4-4.south east) -- cycle;
\node[font=\Huge,shift={(-1,-2)}] at (A) {$0$}; 
\node[font=\Huge,shift={(1,3)}] at (A) {$0$};
\matrix[
    right =of A.north east,
    anchor=north west,
    nodes={mysmallnode}
    ] (B) {%
    \underline{a}_1  \\
    \underline{a}_2 \\
    \underline{a}_3 \\
    \\
    \underline{a}_M\\
    \underline{b}\\
    };
\foreach \ind in {1,2,...,5}{
    \draw (B-\ind-1.south west) -- (B-\ind-1.south east);
}
\draw[dotted] (B-4-1.north) -- (B-4-1.south);
\matrix[
    right =4em of B.north east,
    anchor=north west,
    nodes={draw,mysmallnode}
    ] (C) {%
    |[fill=yellow!10!white]|\\
    |[fill=yellow!30!white]|\\
    |[fill=yellow!50!white]|\\
    \\
    |[fill=yellow!70!white]|\\
    |[mylongnode, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=yellow!90!white]|\underline{\Dot{f}}\\
    };
\path (B-4-1) -- node[midway] {$=$} (C-4-1);
\draw[dotted] (C-4-1.north) -- (C-4-1.south);
% delimiters:
\foreach \mymatr in {A,B,C}
{
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=4pt]\mymatr.north west) -- (\mymatr.north west) -- (\mymatr.south west) -- ([xshift=4pt]\mymatr.south west);
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=-4pt]\mymatr.north east) -- (\mymatr.north east) -- (\mymatr.south east) -- ([xshift=-4pt]\mymatr.south east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

Or with ordinary delimiter:
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[   
    every matrix/.append style={
        left delimiter={[},
        right delimiter={]},
        }
 ]
\matrix[
    nodes={mylargenode},
    column 6/.style={nodes={mysmallnode}},
    row 6/.style={nodes={mylonglargenode}}
    ] (A) {%
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!10!white]| \\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!30!white]|\\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!50!white]|\\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue,dotted]| \\
    &&&&&|[draw=blue, fill=blue!70!white]|\\
    &&&&& |[mylongnode,pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=blue!40!white, draw=blue]|\Dot{F}\\
    };
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \ind in {1,2,3,5}
    {
    \draw[green!70!black,fill=green!40!lightgray] (A-\ind-\ind.north west) -- (A-\ind-\ind.north east) -- (A-\ind-\ind.south east) -- cycle;
    \node[anchor=north east] at (A-\ind-\ind.north east) {R};
    }
\end{scope}
\draw[dotted, green!70!black] (A-4-4.north west) -- (A-4-4.north east) -- (A-4-4.south east) -- cycle;
\node[font=\Huge,shift={(-1,-2)}] at (A) {$0$}; 
\node[font=\Huge,shift={(1,3)}] at (A) {$0$};
\matrix[
    right =of A.north east,
    anchor=north west,
    nodes={mysmallnode}
    ] (B) {%
    \underline{a}_1  \\
    \underline{a}_2 \\
    \underline{a}_3 \\
    \\
    \underline{a}_M\\
    \underline{b}\\
    };
\foreach \ind in {1,2,...,5}{
    \draw (B-\ind-1.south west) -- (B-\ind-1.south east);
}
\draw[dotted] (B-4-1.north) -- (B-4-1.south);
\matrix[
    right =4em of B.north east,
    anchor=north west,
    nodes={draw,mysmallnode}
    ] (C) {%
    |[fill=yellow!10!white]|\\
    |[fill=yellow!30!white]|\\
    |[fill=yellow!50!white]|\\
    \\
    |[fill=yellow!70!white]|\\
    |[mylongnode, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=yellow!90!white]|\underline{\Dot{f}}\\
    };
\path (B-4-1) -- node[midway] {$=$} (C-4-1);
\draw[dotted] (C-4-1.north) -- (C-4-1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How nice is yours, too. I'll vote for it now.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!

Comment: I used this one in my dissertation and I am very happy with the result.

Comment: @TariniRamsewak You're welcome! I'm happy my answer is useful.

Comment: Hello, I had a question. Is it possible to resize this structure without manipulating any of the environments? I tried using the figure environment(scale=0.5), but it does not work. @CarLaTeX

Comment: @TariniRamsewak Try with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]`

Comment: @TariniRamsewak See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture

Answer (score 11):

It is indeed a bit tedious. (**EDIT**: Fixed the first `R` to become math mode, mille grazie to @Sebastiano!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=mat1]
  \path node (R0) {$R$} foreach \X [remember=\X as \lastX (initially 0)] in
  {1,...,4}
  {\ifnum\X=3
    node[below right=1.5em of R\lastX] (R\X) {$\phantom{R}$}
   \else
    node[below right=1.5em of R\lastX] (R\X)  {$R$}
   \fi
   };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[fill=green!70!black] 
   foreach \X in {0,1,2,4} {
   ([xshift=-1em]R\X.north west) -- ([yshift=-1em]R\X.south east)
   coordinate(b\X)
   |- cycle};
   \draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=-1em]R3.north west) -- ([yshift=-1em]R3.south east)
   coordinate(b3) |- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \node[pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=purple,anchor=north west,
  minimum height=6em] (F) at ([yshift=-1em]R4.south east) {$F$}; 
  \draw[densely dotted] ([yshift=-1em]R3.south east-|R4.south east)
   rectangle  (F.east|-R3.north);
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(40+10*\X)}] in {0,1,2,4} 
  {\draw[fill=purple!\Y] ([yshift=-1em]R\X.south east-|R4.south east)
   rectangle  (F.east|-R\X.north);}
 \end{scope} 
 \path (mat1.south west) -- (mat1.north east)
  node[pos=0.3,font=\Large] {$0$} node[pos=0.7,font=\Large] {$0$};
 \draw[thick] ([xshift=0.7em]mat1.north west) -| (mat1.south west) -- ++ (0.7em,0)
 ([xshift=-0.7em]mat1.north east) -| (mat1.south east) -- ++ (-0.7em,0);
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=mat2]
  \foreach \X [remember=\X as \lastX (initially 0)] in {1,2,3}
  {\path ([xshift=1em]mat1.east|-R\lastX.north) --
  ([xshift=2.5em]mat1.east|-b\lastX) node[midway] (a\X) {$a_{\X}$};}
  \path ([xshift=1em]mat1.east|-R4.north) --
  ([xshift=2.5em]mat1.east|-b4) node[midway] (aM) {$a_{M}$};
  \node[below=0.5em of aM] (b) {$b$}; 
 \end{scope}
 \draw[thick] ([xshift=0.5em]mat2.north west) -| (mat2.south west) -- ++ 
 (0.5em,0)
 ([xshift=-0.5em]mat2.north east) -| (mat2.south east) -- ++ (-0.5em,0);
  \foreach \X in {0,...,4}
  {\draw (mat2.west|-b\X) -- (mat2.east|-b\X);}
 %
 \node[anchor=west] (eq) at (mat2.east|-mat1.center) {$=$};
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=mat3]
  \node[pattern=dots,anchor=north west,pattern color=yellow!60!orange,
  minimum height=6em] (f) at ([xshift=0.1em]eq.east|-F.north) {$f$}; 
  \foreach \X [remember=\X as \lastX (initially 0),
  evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(30*\X+10)}] in {1,2,3}
  {\fill[yellow!\Y] ([xshift=0.1em]eq.east|-R\lastX.north) rectangle
  (f.east|-b\lastX); }
  \fill[yellow] ([xshift=0.1em]eq.east|-R4.north) rectangle
  (f.east|-b4); 
  \draw[densely dotted] (f.center|-b2) -- (f.center|-b3);
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,4}
  {\draw (mat3.west|-b\X) -- (mat3.east|-b\X);}
 \draw[thick] ([xshift=0.3em]mat3.north west) -| (mat3.south west) -- ++ 
 (0.3em,0)
 ([xshift=-0.3em]mat3.north east) -| (mat3.south east) -- ++ (-0.3em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spectacular! There is the first R on the top left that is not in math-mode. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Mille grazie!

Comment: @JouleV Thanks! The second code shouldn't be there so I removed it. (I have one file for answers and accidentally copied the code for another answer, too.)

Comment: I hope I've been of some help to you. This is what I so much regret about my mistakes, which are the result of naivety and which, by emphasizing my mistakes, the haters find fertile ground in my regard. Peraphs is better "grazie mille". Why? See this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvS_BVda9ww. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been useful.
I learnt quite a few things.