# Problem for scaling a geometric figure with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code shows an offset of the calculate point when I use the `scale=1.25`.
I have the possibility to use `transform canvas={scale=1.25}` with a `scope` but this leads to other difficulties like the need to create a `bounding box` manually.
This is very annoying because on a complex geometrical construction the shifts can combine and result in a false figure.
In general this happens as soon as distance calculations are used.
Is there a way to avoid this problem?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document} 
\parindent=0pt

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
 \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
 \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
 \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
 \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
 \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
 \path[coordinate] let 
   \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
   \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
   \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
   \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
    in (barycentric cs:E={-\n2/1cm},F={\n1/1cm}) coordinate (D);
 \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
    \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
     in (barycentric cs:E={-\n2/1cm},F={\n1/1cm}) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
     \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=1.25}]
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
     in (barycentric cs:E={-\n2/1cm},F={\n1/1cm}) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
     \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{scope}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (18,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @pascal974 Interesting link because I did not know the existence of several macros but unfortunately not because as `transform canvas` everything is scaled, which I do not want (line thickness, fonts etc.) and the `bounding box`is lost. The good way is to improve some calculations, or even to avoid them. The pgf maintainers have given me some ideas. The problem after a `scale` is that rounding errors are propagated and sometimes their accumulation is a problem. The very good solution would be to do the calculations only with `lua`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment pretty quickly (I thought), I had seen that it works like transform canvas. I didn't see that you replied. Thank's for your explanation. 
The link was 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
A solution to the problem of propagating errors would be the computation of the barycenter directly (using `calc`) without invoking the change of coordinates on the canvas.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz, fullpage}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document} 
\parindent=0pt


Computing $D$ directly as a barycenter of $E$ and $F$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
  in (${-\n2/1cm}*(E) +{\n1/1cm}*(F)$) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
  \filldraw[blue!70!black, opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt)
  node[below right, opacity=1] {$\point$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
Computing $D$ by invoking the barycentric system through
\texttt{barycenter cs:}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
  in (barycentric cs:E={-\n2/1cm},F={\n1/1cm}) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
  \filldraw [black, opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt)
  node[below right, opacity=1] {$\point$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}
Computing $D$ directly as a barycenter of $E$ and $F$ $+$
\texttt{scale=1.25}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
  in (${-\n2/1cm}*(E) +{\n1/1cm}*(F)$) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
  \filldraw [blue!70!black, opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt)
  node[below right, opacity=1] {$\point$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
Computing $D$ by invoking the barycentric system through
\texttt{barycenter cs:} $+$ \texttt{scale=1.25}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \draw[help lines](0,0) grid (18,1);
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(C) at (10,0);
  \coordinate(B) at (6,0);
  \path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=.5](E);
  \path (B) -- (C) coordinate[pos=.5](F);
  \path[coordinate] let 
    \p1 = ($ (B) - (E) $),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($ (B) - (F) $),
    \n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
  in (barycentric cs:E={-\n2/1cm},F={\n1/1cm}) coordinate (D);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F}{
    \filldraw [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt)
    node[below right, opacity=1] {$\point$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```